# How do I change order of these materials?

Tags: materials, export, .fbx

[image]

I want to rearrange these materials for example I want M_Body to be on top.

Comment: Materials are listed alphabetically, only way to rearrange them is by renaming

Answer (score 1):

As Duarte says, Materials are listed alphabetically, you need to rename them

Comment: That doesn't change the order in the drop down material browser, as Duarte pointed out they are listed alphabetically.

Comment: oh sorry you're right